# How to click on the link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Editing description.
I'm developing a script.
This script download a page for authorization via curl (php).
After that I need to click on button ("LOGIN") for entering my login and password.

```
<li class="login_menu_button"> <a href="javascript:void(0);">LOGIN</a> </li>
```

I just try to use this code, but it doesn't work

How can I realize click on this button? This button just switch from one form to another (from sign in to login) without page reload.
Thanks.

Comment: I want to click on link(this is a button), but I can't do this.

Comment: Are you saying you want to know when the link is clicked?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Can you edit your question description and be more clear? What do you want to achieve, what you have tried to achieve it and explain what you expect the source code to do. Thank you.

Comment: No. I do some script. Firsly, I download page via curl, after I need click the button ("login") for entering login and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mistake in your code getElementByTagName should be getElementsByTagName which returns a array of elements, so you need need to pick the matching element in the array, your better off using the below:

```
var lnk = document.querySelector(".login_menu_button");

lnk.onclick = function(e){
    // your custom logic here
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

it will select your li element and bind the onclick to your handler and prevent the default action of your link.

http://jsfiddle.net/xkx9mvuw/1/

Comment: It doesn't work. I do authorize script for one site. For test, I just download this page and add your script in the end of source code of this page.

Comment: what do you want to happen in the onclick function?

Comment: I want to open form to authorize on the site.
When you just download a page, you can see a registration form. For authorize you should click on "login" button.

Comment: where is the form, on same page or on another page?

Comment: document.getElementById("formId").submit();

Comment: I'm just add to end of this page your code(<script>document.getElementById("formId").submit();</script>), and my page is redirected to another. But doesn't work :| I want to say, that this form is hidden. And when you click "LOGIN", you can see this login form not hidden.

Comment: you can put javascript to show your form in my function above

Comment: document.getElementById('formContainerId').style.display = 'block'; replace formContainerId with the id of the div containing your form or the form itself

Comment: This is a code: http://notepad.cc/frawoni15
Form with "sign in" is hidden, but Login form is hidden too.
When I clicking on "LOGIN", I'm just redirecting...

Comment: change document.getElementById("login_form").submit(); to document.getElementById('login_form').style.display = 'block';

Comment: the first to lines are setting the display to block, this will show both forms, remove these two lines if you want to keep them hidden until you click on the logon link

Comment: I removed this 2 lines. But now nothing happend. Just download a page. When I click a button "LOGIN", then I redirecting to some page (I don't know which page, because I'm testing on my hosting). (You can saw a source code of this script in notepad.cc link, which I send you earlier)

Comment: change to: lnk.onclick = function(e){
    document.getElementById('login_form').style.display = 'block';
    e.preventDefault();
}

Comment: ok, what's the next? 
Automatically this form doesn't open.
But when I click on "LOGIN", then this form is opening.

Comment: ok good, now what do you need to do, isnt that your solution?, dont you want the user to fill in the form?

Comment: No.
I'm need to open this form by script.
I developing a script.
Algorithm:
1. Download a page via curl (php)
2. Click on "LOGIN" (the form for authorization by login&password will be open)
3. Entering my login and password

Comment: ok, you need to add javascript to fill the username & password and to submit the form, correct?

Comment: yeah, I understand you. But now silly question: HOW I CAN DO THIS?)
Input for login: <input name="login" id="login_form" type="text">
Input for password: <input name="password" id="login_form_password" type="password">

Comment: document.getElementById("login_form").value = "john123";
document.getElementById("login_form_password").value = "password123";
document.getElementById("formId").submit();

Comment: formId needs to be what your form Id attribute value is

Comment: ok, thanks so much)
One more question: how can I do "some magic"?
In php I just download a page like this:
some code this... cookies, useragent;
$b = curl_exec($curl);
And now $b - it's a html code of my page.
How can I work with this page? After curl_exec, I just write ?> and my script is ending. If I add <script>code...code</sctipt> it's doesn't work.

Comment: new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756505/how-i-can-send-html-code-from-php-to-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Just try something like this(Edited `javascript:void(0);` present in your code):

```js
$(function(){
  $("li a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var hrefPath = $(this).attr('href');
     alert(hrefPath);
     //use it in your window.location
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="login_menu_button"> <a href="test-page">LOGIN</a> </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be wise to use raw javascript for things like this (i.e adding behaviors to DOM elements)

I generally use jquery.

so with Jquery detecting a click on a link is as simple as defining a 'click' event handler like so:

```
$('li a').click(function(e) {
    //handle the click here.
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Cheers